# How to add seperate file with functions in Android Studio

Tags: android, function, kotlin

I'd like to have a file with some functions that I can add to my projects. So I can just add that file and then use the same things again.

I've made a new file, added a simple function and tried to run it in my MainActivity. 
Mainactivity can "see" my function, but the app crashes as soon as the function is being run.
Is it possible to make a seperate file like this and have access to all functions, as if they were in my MainActivity?

Just for testing I did this:

MainActivity.kt

```
mToast("Its working", 0, 500)
```

funs.tk

```
package com.myname.app

import android.view.Gravity
import android.widget.Toast

fun mToast(t: String, x: Int, y: Int) {
    val toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity().applicationContext, t, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, x, y)
    toast.show()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not create new `MainActivity` instance in your helper function. Instead, pass context as a parameter:

```
fun mToast(context: Context, t: String, x: Int, y: Int) {
    val toast = Toast.makeText(context, t, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, x, y)
    toast.show()
}
```